Problem with link stage while try use yaml-cpp "library"
Hi I am try create static library from yaml-cpp.
Windows x64 to use in my own project
I did next steps:
Clone repo prepare build dir and move to it
mkdir build
cd build

Configure Cmake in different variants:
1)
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DYAML_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../for_D7 ..




cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DYAML_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../for_D7 -DYAML_CPP_BUILD_CONTRIB=ON -DYAML_CPP_BUILD_TOOLS=ON -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++17" ..

Execute building
cmake --build . --config Release --target install

And and try same shit for using MSVC.
I`v got for one case yaml-cpp.lib (when i try ti get it with MSVC) andd libyaml-cpp.a (for MinGW)
I try to use both of them in my app.
This is how in my main.cpp:
if (argc == 2 && (strstr(argv[1], ".yaml") != NULL)) {
       char* file_folder;
       char* file_name;
       char* mode;
       char* dll_folder;
       char* dll_name;
       int chunk_len;
       int port;
       
       try {
           YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile(argv[1]);
           if (config["sample_source"]) {
               YAML::Node sample_source = config["sample_source"];
               if (sample_source["file_folder_env_var"]) {
                   const char* ts = sample_source["file_folder_env_var"].as<std::string>().c_str();
                   file_folder = get_env_variable(ts);
                   if (file_folder == NULL) {
                       file_folder = (char*)DEFAULT_SIGNAL_DATA_PATH;
                   }
               } else {
                   file_folder = (char*)"NOT SET";
               }

               if (sample_source["file_name"]) {
                   file_name = (char*)sample_source["file_name"].as<std::string>().c_str();
               } else {
                   file_name = (char*)"NOT SET";
               }

               if (sample_source["mode"]) {
                   mode = (char*)sample_source["mode"].as<std::string>().c_str();
               } else {
                   mode = (char*)"NOT SET";
               }

               if (sample_source["rtlsdr_dll"]["path"]) {
                   dll_folder = (char*)sample_source["rtlsdr_dll"]["path"].as<std::string>().c_str();
               } else {
                   dll_folder = (char*)"NOT SET";
               }

               if (sample_source["rtlsdr_dll"]["file"]) {
                   dll_name = (char*)sample_source["rtlsdr_dll"]["file"].as<std::string>().c_str();
               } else {
                   dll_name = (char*)"NOT SET";
               }

               if (sample_source["port"]) {
                   port = sample_source["port"].as<int>();
               } else {
                   port = -1;
               }

               if (sample_source["chunk_len"]) {
                   chunk_len = sample_source["chunk_len"].as<int>();
               } else {
                   chunk_len = -1;
               }

               printf("Mode: %s\n", mode);
               printf("File path: %s\n", file_folder);
               printf("File name: %s\n", file_name);
               printf("DLL path: %s\n", dll_folder);
               printf("DLL name: %s\n", dll_name);
               printf("Port: %d\n", port);
               printf("Chunk len: %d\n", chunk_len);
           }
       } 
       catch (const std::exception& ex) {
           printf("Error: %s\n", ex.what());
           return -1;
       }
       return 0;
   }

My app compiled - i get object files. Compile in that way:
gcc -c -g -D_DEBUG -D_D7 -std=c++17 -Iexternal_binaries\yaml-cpp\include -Iexternal_binaries\ffftw3.3.5_x64 -Iinclude src\rtl-sdr-wrapper\wrapper.cpp src\rtl-sdr-wrapper\rcv_test.cpp src\common.cpp src\main.cpp

But linkage fails
g++ -o build/release/spectro_mk2.exe wrapper.o rcv_test.o common.o main.o -L"external_binaries\yaml-cpp\lib" -L"external_binaries\ffftw3.3.5_x64" -lyaml -llibfftw3-3 -lws2_32
Output is too large but in breef It couldnt find some symbols. I make check like this:
nm libyaml-cpp.a > symbols.txt
findstr "__imp__ZN4YAML8LoadFileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE" symbols.txt
findstr "__imp__ZTVN4YAML9ExceptionE" symbols.txt
findstr "__imp__ZN4YAML6detail6memory11create_nodeEv" symbols.txt
findstr "__imp__ZN4YAML11InvalidNodeD1Ev" symbols.txt
findstr "__imp__ZN4YAML23RepresentationExceptionE" symbols.txt
findstr "__imp__ZN4YAML13BadConversionE" symbols.txt
findstr "__imp__ZN4YAML6detail9node_data12empty_scalarB5cxx11Ev" symbols.txt
findstr "__imp__ZN4YAML12BadSubscriptE" symbols.txt
findstr "__imp__ZN4YAML6detail13memory_holder5mergeERS1_" symbols.txt

No such symbols
Same trouble when i try use static library made by MSVC - same linker errors
I`am very new to all that CMake stuff))
@JesseBeder
I wait for help with usage if that exact lib
And be grateful for explain how that CMake stuff work in coomon cocept

The prefix __imp__ means that the symbol is expected to be defined in a shared (dll) library. For link with a static library, you need to define a macro YAML_CPP_STATIC_DEFINE (either in CMake code, or in the C++ code).

I create dir build.
Open it in terminal and run commnd:
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DYAML_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../for_D7 ..

In CMakeLists.txt there are already present^

Same shit
g++ -o build/release/spectro_mk2.exe wrapper.o rcv_test.o base_framework.o consoles.o common.o main.o -L"external_binaries\yaml-cpp\lib" -L"external_binaries\ffftw3.3.5_x64" -lyaml-cpp -llibfftw3-3 -lws2_32
E:/Soft/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: main.o: in function `read_config(char*, char*, char*, char*, char*, int*, int*, int*)':
c:\Users\d7\source\repos\D7-RTL-SDR-C/src/main.cpp:35:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN4YAML8LoadFileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE


Why do you post a code in the comments? If you want to demonstrate that your question differs from the duplicate, then update the question post itself with your fair attempt. That attempt is expected to take into account answer(s) to the duplicate question.

Because i am noob here)))

Thanks.
After i add define in my header  before include yaml-cpp  - all OK

In think  that such information has to be in readme)))
